# Eclipse Build Path - declared packages does not match

Tags: java, eclipse

In my Eclipse project I added source folder "pmml-evaluator/src/main/java" as a source folder, so I expect that all the subfolders are considered to be packages names.

Unfortunately the Eclipse expects package not "org.jpmml.evaluator" but "main.java.org.jpmml.evaluator". Did I missed something or it is Eclipse bug?

Eclipse Mars.1 Release 4.5.1

> The declared package "org.jpmml.evaluator" does not match the expected package 
>    "main.java.org.jpmml.evaluator"

[image]

Comment: Is it a maven project? You can generate an eclipse `.project` file by running `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and then import the project in eclipse and all source folder settings should be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven doesn't know that is a java project because it's not specified in the pom.xml, you should add:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and reimport. Otherwise you can change source folder in java build path

PS: Make sure you delete .settings and .project before reimporting, or eclipse will import it the same way as before

Comment: I thought maven had sensible java defaults? This section is only required if you want to change the defaullt compliter settings?

Comment: maven does. the maven plugin from eclipse sometimes fails to default to java, it happened to me lots of times, however if you add a plugin specific for java (compiler, ejb, war) it works

Comment: You mean the M2E (maven-eclipse integration?). That's likely. I always use maven from the command line :-)